# How to count references to fields given the definitions of views?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, query, dependencies

I have a bootstrapping script which defines views to be exposed to the data users in `public` schema.
It filters out sensitive fields from the tables in `private` schema, also makes various aggregations.

I wish to understand which fields (in tables) are referenced the most, especially in `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` and similar statements (which would indicate that the field should be indexed).

The problem is that the references are nested and aliased so simple(-ish) regular expressions don't seem to be enough.

For example:

```sql
CREATE VIEW public.user AS (
  SELECT name FROM private.user
);

CREATE VIEW public.device AS (
  SELECT user_name, type FROM private.device
);

CREATE VIEW public.user_size AS (
  SELECT name, count(*)
  FROM public.user u
  JOIN public.device d ON u.name = d.user_name
  GROUP BY name
);
```

would ideally detect that `private.user.name` is referenced 2 times (once in `JOIN` and once in `GROUP BY`) and `private.device.user_name` is referenced 1 time (in `JOIN`).

Are there any means to help automate this process? DB is PostgreSQL, if that makes a difference.

Comment: You can easily figure out which base table column appears in the definition of a view. But the view definition is stored as a parse tree, so you'd have to write C code and use PostgreSQL internals for that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, could you please elaborate on how to access the aforementioned parse trees?

Comment: `SELECT r.ev_action FROM pg_class AS v JOIN pg_depend AS d ON v.oid = d.refobjid JOIN pg_rewrite AS r ON r.oid = d.objid WHERE v.relkind = 'v' AND v.relname = 'viewname' AND d.classid = 'pg_rewrite'::regclass AND d.deptype = 'i' AND r.rulename = '_RETURN';`